# How to make VALUES statement optional in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, option-type

I have a sparql query with VALUES statement in it.

```
VALUES (?Name ?department) {
       ("Marc" "Marketing")
       ("John" "IT")
}
```

I want to make it optional; to be run only when ?Name is Marc or John.
Otherwise, it should be ignored.
I tried:

```
OPTIONAL{    
   VALUES (?Name ?department) {
          ("Marc" "Marketing")
          ("John" "IT")
    }
}.
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas???

Comment: Which SPARQL processor are you using? I tried this with Apache Jena and it worked fine.

Comment: I am working on java project with Apache jena too. The problem is that when ?Name takes the value "Marc", the code above is not run.

Comment: Check that the value is correct - it might be a language tagged literal?

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 `BIND` in combination with `IF` can do this.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is not to make the VALUES clause optional, since this will return everything whether it matches any part of the VALUES filter or not. Instead consider using MINUS in combination with UNION:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX :   <http://example#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  {
    ?person :name ?name ;
            :department ?department .
    MINUS {
      VALUES ?name { "Marc" "John" }
    }
  }
  UNION {
    ?person :name ?name ;
            :department ?department .
    VALUES (?name ?department) {
      ("Marc" "Marketing")
      ("John" "IT")
    }
  }
}
```

The first part of the expression matches anyone who is *not* called Marc or John. The second part applies the VALUES filter as usual.